# Rewrite .html to .php using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite condition and rule which is.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^[^*]+$ index.php [L]
```

I need to replace `.html` with `.php` in `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0`.

The reason is, I am rewriting my url's to `.html` but when this file checks for an existing file it fails due to `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0` looking for file `thefile.html`,

I need it to look for `thefile.php`.

Comment: Keep in mind this WILL NOT interpret HTML as PHP. Which seems like the only real reason one would think this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For rewriting `.html` extensions to existing `.php` files with the same name, try this rule instead of what you had:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

What you have just rewrites any non-existent file to index.php

Comment: Thanks, however, if the file does not exist I get a 404 error with that code. I need it to goto the file if it exists as .php (but the request will be .html), if not got index.php

Comment: I added 2 more lines to the end so it should in addition, redirect non-existent files to index.php

Comment: For those looking for an explanation, the second RewriteRule works because .htaccess is called on the second pass when looking for the new PHP file.

Answer (score 4):

Solved!

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^[^*]+$ index.php [L]
```

I had to use it twice to firstly, rewite all .html to .php then on the request for.php the second condition comes into play.